# self.navigationController is set to nil by iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have many ViewControllers in my app and I push and pop them successfully as needed.
The navigationController is available and does its job.

But after some time, it is automatically set to nil by iOS. I don't know where this is happening in the code, and even more intriguing, how can that be possible at all?

Isn't a navigationController an object that exists throughout the existence of the app?

I would share some code, if only I knew what to look for.

At that point, when navigationController has become nil, I cannot push any ViewControllers anymore and the only thing left is to exit the app and relaunch it, but that's not something I can ask the user to do.

So, what makes iOS to set a fine working navigationController to nil?

I see nothing unusual in Logcat and there's no crash or related warning.

Meanwhile I was able to narrow down where it happens. It is when I change the rootViewController:

```
static func changeRootViewController(window:UIWindow, viewController:UIViewController){
    window.rootViewController?.navigationController?.removeFromParent()
    window.rootViewController?.navigationDrawerController?.removeFromParent()
    window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.removeFromParent()
    window.rootViewController = nil
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0 / 256 , green: 238.0 / 256 , blue: 241.0 / 256 , alpha: 1.0)
    window.rootViewController =  viewController
 
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Which is called this way:

```
let driverArrivedUv = GeneralFunctions.instantiateViewController(pageName: "DriverArrivedUV") as! DriverArrivedUV
                
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: driverArrivedUv)
                navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
                
                UIView.transition(with: self.window,
                                  duration: 0.25,
                                  options: .showHideTransitionViews,
                                  animations: {GeneralFunctions.changeRootViewController(window: self.window, viewController: navigationController)
                                    
                } ,
                                  completion: nil)
```

Comment: You are probably presenting the view controller where navigationController is nil

Comment: no, I am not using .present, only .pushViewController and it is working file until, all of a sudden, iOS has set navigationController to  nil

Comment: You haven’t provided enough information about your code. Please make sure to edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Well, the problem is that I have no clue how to reproduce it. It works fine for some time and then, bang!, the navigationcontroller has become nil. As it is impossible to set it to nil by own code, there must be 'something' that triggers iOS to do so. So the question is: what should I look for?

Comment: iOS does nothing if you don't ask it to do it. It is probably related to setting the `rootViewController` as you mentioned in comments

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to *only* expect a `navigationController` to be set if your VC actually is part of the navigation stack of that navigation controller.

Meaning: did you use `.setViewControllers(...)` or `.pushViewController(...)` to display that specific ViewController?
Or did you rather use `.present(...)` to show the VC? Because if you present, that ViewController is *not* part of the navigation stack. (It will also not have a navigation bar or a back button visible because of that.)

If you need a navigationController to push something inside of a presented ViewController, first wrap that VC in a new NavigationController and then present the new navigationController on your previously existing one.

Comment: I don't use .present. My VC are all shown with .pushViewController. and everytime I push a VC I also set .rootViewController by removing the previous one and setting the new one.

Comment: Then my main suspicion falls to the VC that you removed from the navigation stack. When you do it, it will not hold a reference to the navigationController anymore. There might be some reasons why the old VC is still alive for a while. (Other parts of the code holding references to it, maybe intentional and maybe unintentional [memory leak]). If then something happens and that VC tries to access the NC, well, it's not part of the navigation stack anymore and the navigationController is nil.

Answer (score 0):

I would force unwrap the `navigationController` in the code and let it fail. At least you get the idea where it failed and maybe you can trace back from there.

So maybe where you have `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` try to use it as `self.navigationController!.pushViewController` and see the stack trace.